# JavaFX MenuBar: Separate mouse click on menu to show corresponding menu items

Tags: javafx-8, menubar

In JavaFX MenuBar, If we click on any menu then it shows corresponding menu items. Now If we don't move our mouse pointer from the clicked menu and drag it horizontally over other menus, then for each menu it shows corresponding menu items. It is the default functionality. But I don't want that.

I want to configure it in a way such that separate mouse click would be necessary to show corresponding menu items. So here If we click on any menu and drag mouse pointer horizontally over another menu then it should do nothing.

**here, by saying mouse click, I meant click & release(not hold the click)**

I searched in StackOverflow & google for any related questions or blog posts but found nothing. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think JavaFX just mimics the typical behaviour of native menu bars and I wonder whether it makes sense, from a user experience point of view, to change this behaviour that most users will expect because they know it.

Comment: I agree. But in my app the use case is slightly different. One menu(suppose, Home) in the MenuBar is implemented like a navigation button (where there is one menu item but I'm firing it once the user clicks the menu, so it seems like they are navigating just like website navigation). But the menu(suppose, X) beside 'Home' has three menu items. So when user clicks X and accidentally hover over 'Home' the home scene loads (like 'Home' was clicked) and I don't want that. thanks, @mipa for your time.